# Native Page Transitions + phonegap + cordova

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, telerik, phonegap-plugins

i am doing simple html and javascript with the native page transition..
i already add the plugin :cordova plugin add https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/NativePageTransitions ..
i follow all the step inside the blog..but my transition page not working..this is my code..sorry i am still newbie..

my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>2PAGE</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function slide(href) {
    window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
        "href" : "3page.html"
    });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="slide('right', '#3page')">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this code correct ? please help me..i follow instruction from : http://www.telerik.com/blogs/native-performance-in-a-hybrid-app-with-native-page-transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the code file there isn't default cordova.js setup, i think because of it this plugin is not working for you.

it's working fine with mine demo project.

So please add

```
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: Kirankumar Dafda thank youuuu to muchhhh ;) it working after i add "<script src="cordova.js"></script>" .. Kirankumar Dafda do you know how to make pull & refresh simplest way for codava phonegap by using javascript html and css ?